# What is the meaning of " bless their little pea-pickin' hearts but TMW has done it again"?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean, especially the usage of 'but'?

- Well, bless their little pea-pickin' hearts but TMW has done it again.

Also what does *TMW* mean?

Comment: We would need further context to fully answer, please [edit] your question to tell us more.

Comment: "TMW" has dozens of meanings.  Likely in this case it's referring to the initials of some person, but without context it's impossible to guess which person.

Comment: Related: [Bless your heart](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93156/bless-your-heart).  It can be quite invective in context.

Comment: It's impossible to analyse this usage of 'but' without knowing what 'bless their little pea-pickin' hearts' conveys. (a) If it's merely mild condecension, the 'but' is a reluctant contrastive: those little-leaguers, I suppose you've got to give it to them, they've gone and done it (triumphed) again! // (b) If it's a term of endearment, the 'but' must be a "you're not going to believe this', _hold on to your hat, what an achievement!_ intensifying marker.  '_TMW has only gone and done it again!_

Comment: The question is about an abbreviation that is specific to a particular context, not an established component of English language and usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bless your little pea-pickin' heart" was a catch phrase coined by Tennessee Ernie Ford, a country singer and entertainer, in the middle of the last century.

> [Ford] earned the nickname "The Ol' Pea-Picker" due to his catchphrase, "Bless your pea-pickin' heart!" He began using the term during his disc jockey days on KXLA.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennessee_Ernie_Ford#The_Ford_Show)</sub>

The term is one of mild condescension, a countrified variation of "Bless your heart," which was used more in Southern and rural US localities and in earlier times. "Pea-pickin'" is probably a slightly sweetened variation of "cotton-pickin'", which was a kind of minced oath in that era (i.e., a substitute for a word like "goddamn").

Comment: I look at it as more of a term of endearment instead of condescension.